# Angular 9 Reactive Form failing to update value

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form with nested form arrays. Works great, never had an issue until now.

```
  contractForm = new FormGroup({
    ContractNumber:new FormControl(''),
    ...
    Items: this.fb.array([])
  });
```

The items array gets populated later.

My issue comes when I try to change the value of one of them. Never really had a problem before. However this function:

```
removeSerial(rowIndex, snIndex){
    const itemsArray = this.contractForm.get('Items') as FormArray;
    const serialArray = itemsArray.at(rowIndex).get('SerialNumbers') as FormArray;  
    serialArray.at(snIndex).get('STATUS').setValue('Inactive'); 
    console.log(serialArray.at(snIndex).get('STATUS').value); 
    console.log(this.contractForm.value);
  }
```

the first console.log shows the expected "Inactive" value. However, when I print the value of the form, the value is not changed. What am I missing here? If it matters the component is set to "changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush"

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: If I get desperate. Would take a bit to recreate enough of it. Still playing around first...but running out of ideas.

Comment: after consoe try this serialArray.at(snIndex).get('STATUS').updateValueandValidity()

Comment: No such luck. No change.

Comment: However: serialArray.updateValueAndValidity() ; did work! Success! Thanks for pointing me down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to add serialArray.updateValueAndValidity(); Thanks to Chellappan for getting me there.